# Unable to Customize Kendo Calendar Month templates with Knockout Kendo JS Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I have customized the `Kendo Calendar Month Template` Reference found [Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/oqol) `with out knockout-kendo.js`. Official Kendo Reference from [Here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/template).

The problem is when i use the below code in `knockout-kendo.js binding its not getting compiled`. Take a look at this [`Knockout-kendo.js` with Calendar at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshKDev/hbcd1e7d/). If i remove the `month view template code`, its working. How do i resolve this with knockout-kendo.js?

```
           $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                dates: birthdays,
                month: {
                    // template for dates in month view
                    content: '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == "failure") { #' +
                                 '<div class="failure">' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #' +
                             '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == "success") { #' +
                                 '<div class="success">' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #' +
                             '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == "none") { #' +
                                 '<div class="none">' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #'

                },
                change: function () {
                    scheduler.date(this.value());
                },
            });
```

**The Error is below :**

[image]

So, the Question is How to Use Month View in Knockout-Kendo.js binding?

**Update:**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your Kendo Template you need to escape your quotes. So, you can use `&quot;` rather than just the `"`.

Like:

```
content: '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == &quot;failure&quot;) { #' +
                                 '<div class=&quot;failure&quot;>' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #' +
                             '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == &quot;success&quot;) { #' +
                                 '<div class=&quot;success&quot;>' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #' +
                             '# if (isInArray(data.date, data.dates, data) == &quot;none&quot;) { #' +
                                 '<div class=&quot;none&quot;>' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +
                             '# } #'
```

You can move the template string into your view model, if it helps.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bfycstr4/

Comment: Thanks for your Time and Quick response. Still its gives me an error. Please look at my updated image in my question.

Comment: This line is not getting compiled `'<div class=&quot;failure&quot;>' + '#= data.value #' + '</div>' +`. Second line.

Comment: In the fiddle or where?  The fiddle is working properly, right?

Comment: There was a small change that I made to the isInArray function too, so it is not reading `dates` from the arguments.

Comment: Yes this is working absolutely fine in fiddle. I'm using in Visual Studio 2013 asp.net MVC Project. There only i'm facing issue as i mentioned ablove.

Comment: A small hint helped. :) `You can move the template string into your view model, if it helps.` +1 for that. Thank You.