# Unable to customize Kendo UI calendar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Is there a way to use $.inArray function in the month content attribute of kendo calendar, as the customized function in the script side for angular JS application. I checked for knockout it is working fine. check the below link
[Unable to Customize Kendo Calendar Month templates with Knockout Kendo JS Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721306/unable-to-customize-kendo-calendar-month-templates-with-knockout-kendo-js-bindin)

As same like this, I need to access IsInarray function in the script side from content template in AngularJS. Please provide solution.

below the sample link.
http://dojo.telerik.com/OmUge/7

Comment: Provide your code in your question as well, please.

Comment: Facing issues, while pasting the code. so only provided the dojo sample. Please check and help me with the solution